# Erro em hash de vetores com deslocamento

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um hash de vetores com deslocamento para tratamento de colisoes. Meu programa esta dando um erro. Alguem pode me ajudar a encontra o motivo do erro?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int hash (int c, int M){
    return c%M;
}

int deslocamento(int c){
    return (c%2) + 1;
}

void inserir(int chave, int pos, int hash_table[], int M){
    if(hash_table[pos] == -1){
    hash_table[pos] = chave;
    }else{
        int novaposicao = pos + deslocamento(chave);
        while(novaposicao > 7){
            novaposicao = pos + deslocamento(chave);
        }
    hash_table[novaposicao] = chave;
    }
}

void imprimeTabelaEncadeada(int tabela[], int m){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        if((tabela[i] == -1)){
            printf("Vazio");
        }else{
        printf("Chave: %d", tabela[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
  } 

int main(){
    int M = 7;
    int hash_table[7]; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < M; i++){
        hash_table[i] = -1;
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < M; i++){
        printf("%d", hash_table[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int N = 5;
    int chaves[] = {24,76,39,61,25};
    int pos;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pos = hash(chaves[i], M);
        printf("%d\n", pos);
        inserir(chaves[i], pos, hash_table, M);
    }
    imprimeTabelaEncadeada(hash_table, M);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Essa função `deslocamento` sempre retorna 1 ou 2. Isto está certo? Se sim, por quê?

Comment: Entao essa funcao deslocamento é algo que tinha na questao, eu acho que seria mais facil procurar um valor vazio no vetor e atribuia nele o meu novo valor. Mas pelo que eu entendi era para essa funcao fazer o deslocamento dos itens do vetor caso houvesse conflito.

Comment: Você não poderia fornecer mais informações ? "I'm a doctor Jim, not a telepath"